# Netlify fbclid redirects

Tags: facebook, redirect, netlify

Can you please help me with the netlify redirect rules for the new `fbclid` field that Facebook adds to urls? It is terrible for analytics and cache.
What I have tried:

```
/mysite.test/*fbclid /mysite.test/:splat 301
```

Comment: `/mysite.test/*fbclid` would only match if `fbclid` was a path segment - but it is not, it is a query string parameter. How to match those, see https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/#query-params

Comment: are you trying to redirect, so these do not show in analytics?

Comment: yes. and also to limit the cache requests

Answer (score 3):

Redirects on Netlify have specific rules that aren't always as clear until you test them.

#### With no extra `splat`:

```
https://example.com?id=23&fbclid=huihd8239732buibiee32809jeee2i90
```

You will need a redirect without any wildcard and `:splat`

```
/ id=:id fbclid=:fbclid / 301
```

redirects to: `https://example.com`

#### With extra `splat`:

```
https://example.com/test?id=23&fbclid=huihd8239732buibiee32809jeee2i90
```

A redirect with the wildcard and `:splat` would be needed

```
/* id=:id fbclid=:fbclid /:splat 301!
```

redirects to: `https://example.com/test`

### Solution for above examples combined

`_redirects`

```
/ id=:id fbclid=:fbclid / 301
/* id=:id fbclid=:fbclid /:splat 301!
```

***Note:*** ALL parameters must match to catch the redirect case. In the example above, if there was only an `fbclid` parameter then you should have the following to catch it.

`_redirects`

```
/ fbclid=:fbclid / 301
/ id=:id fbclid=:fbclid / 301
/* fbclid=:fbclid /:splat 301!
/* id=:id fbclid=:fbclid /:splat 301!
```

***Warning:*** **DO NOT** setup a redirects similar to the below examples. They will cause an infinite redirect:

Do not try to redirect to the same paths to strip or add a trailing `/`. Use the admin panel and change the pretty URL settings (Build & deploy > Post processing > Asset optimization).

```
# Do Not ever do these in your redirects
/some-path /some-path/ 301!
/*   /:splat/  301!
```

Comment: It does not seem to work. I added your suggestions but a link like `https://mysite.test/some-link/?fbclid=joffjasjoi7879ioufo` doesn't redirect to `https://mysite.test/some-link/`

Comment: [Here is the test repo I used](https://github.com/talves/netlify-test-redirects) and here is the link [`https://testing-redirects.netlify.com/some-link/?fbclid=huihd8239732buibiee32809jeee2i90`](https://testing-redirects.netlify.com/some-link/?fbclid=huihd8239732buibiee32809jeee2i90) . Make sure you are putting your `_redirects` in the root of your deploy folder.

Comment: It finally worked after I appended an exclamation mark to the rule so that I have at the end `301!`

Comment: You are correct. I missed it on the wildcard paths. Netlify will check for a file existing unless you force the path always. The `!' tells the rule to always redirect even if the path is valid. My bad, I tested the wild cards against invalid paths, so it worked.

Comment: No problem. Thank you very much for your help!