# Analytics shows fbclid and fblogin.htm but I shouldn't have them

Tags: google-analytics, bots, analytics

I created a hugo ssg blog for my mother which is hosted on netlify. The intent of blog was just to keep her busy during pandemic, therefore, it's just lists of articles. No like/dislike, no comments, no other functionalities. Only JS included is Google and Bing Analytics.

I was going through analytics and found random fbclid urls in page visits. After some research I followed advice from this [stackoverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54210842/netlify-fbclid-redirects) and stopped worrying. After few months, I see bots visit on `/fblogin.htm`. Remember,I have not added anything related to FB on the site. There is no fblogin.htm on the site, There is no sharing of blog post on fb. I have no idea why bots from facebook would look for a non-existent page on the site. Is it because of `<meta og:...>` tags in head? Can someone explain to me what is happening here and should I be worried about it? I occasionally get random spikes of 5-15 visits from china, turkey, finland or some other random country via these fb bots. Should I be concerned?

[image: screenshot from analytics report]

Answer (score 0):

*fblogin.htm* should be explored, however `fbclid` is a parameter that Facebook hangs when you click on a post in Facebook that leads to your site.

So if the link to a page of your site is on Facebook (i.e. in a post) and someone has clicked on it, you will find that parameter in Google Analytics append to the landing page.

Comment: But since we never shared the blog on fb. We never promoted the site. As I said, the primary intent was just to keep my mother busy with some creative work. Only a few family members read it when we tell them on phone.

Comment: Also, I would like to add that these random visitor spikes from fb comes from different countries, like china, turkey, philippines,  etc. These places have no remote reason to search for anything which could point to this blog. In face, other than having a seo friendly hugo theme,  I haven't done any seo or promotion on the site. This is what is boggling me.

Comment: Check you have excleded spam and bot by tick option in View settings.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you need to be precise about 'few family members' and 'we tell them on phone' - are you sure how this was shared between them? is anyone Whatsup user or was this shared via Xiaomi or other China phone ?  Also if the blog is not password protected those Facebook variables could just be used by the bots to mimic human behaviour